# Unix date JavaScript: moment with timezone give wrong result

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs, unix-timestamp

I am trying to get date string from unix timestamp with timezone

```
let moment = require('moment-timezone'); 
    let date = moment.unix(1516812300).tz('Asia/Kolkata').format('YYYY-M-DD-H-mm-s');
```

The correct date is `2018/01/24 16:45:00` with timezone `Asia/Kolkata` but  the above code return this `2018-1-24-22-15-0`

Comment: Are you browser in 'Asia/Kolkata' timezone?

Comment: Nop my browser is in UTC timezone

Answer (score 0):

Unixtime do not have 'timezones'. You can recognize that it is always in UCT. And same unixtime will always produce different 'human' time in different timezones. 1516812300 is in fact Wednesday January 24, 2018 22:15:00 (pm) in time zone Asia/Kolkata (IST). Because unixtime is same in same moment in any place of universe, on Moon, Kolkata or in London. So, when you have a day, in Kolkata may be night, while unixtime is absolutely same. So, your 2018/01/24 16:45:00 UCT is relay to 22:15:00 in Kolkata.

Comment: Here is the unix  timestamp for the date `2018/01/24 16:45:00` =1516812300`   but when i convert it with timezone it give wrong result

Comment: This is correct. Because 1516812300 is 16:45:00 in UCT, while in Kolkata 22:15:00. Unixtime is not date, it is just amount of seconds from some time moment. And 'human' time in different in different places, while unixtime is always same.

Comment: You can play with that to understand https://www.epochconverter.com/timezones?q=1516812300&tz=Asia%2FKolkata